# How many palindromic numbers of k figures in base b

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, integers

Let k,b integers $\geq 2$. How many palindromic numbers of k figures can be written in base b?

Comment: Some reviewers may regard my answer as premature, re (for example) OP showing work first.  Fair point.  **However,** this problem seems more like a (math puzzle) than a problem assigned from class, and it requires "thinking outside the box", which is not generally taught in class.  My providing a *premature* answer was an act of rebellion against someone foisting a math puzzle on the OP.  If (instead), the OP voluntarily went to a "puzzle site", it still doesn't seem unreasonable to provide hints, rather than asking the OP to (for ex.), assume $b=8$ and $k=4$ or $k=5$, and look for a pattern.

Comment: @user2661923 You can justify how you would like, it is an answer to a VERY low quality question without any effort put in by the OP (and no effort by you to help them improve their question).

Comment: @MorganRodgers I can't disagree.  I just reacted emotionally to the math-puzzle nature of the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hints:

Each digit must be in $\{0,1,2, \cdots, (b-1)\}$ where it is presumed that the appropriate symbols will be used when (for example) $b = 16.$

**start of protocol**

Presumed that the leftmost digit can not be a $0$.
Thus, there are $(b-1)$ choices for the rightmost digit, 
and $(b)$ choices for the remaining digits.

**end of protocol**

Further you have to explore $k = 2r$ and $k = (2r-1)$ separately.

With $k=2r$, you have r choices to make in accordance with the protocol described above. 
With $k=(2r-1)$, you still have r choices to make.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok, so it's $ (b-1)(b)^{\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor - 1} $.

Comment: @Mattia_Borriello Close, but no.  Consider what happens if $k=5.$

Comment: Oh, I got it, it's $ \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor $ not - 1.

Comment: @Mattia_Borriello **closer**, but still not quite right.  You need a formula that is **simultaneously** accurate when (for example) $k = 2r$ **or** $k = (2r - 1).$  Why not break the situation up into 2 cases, re $k=2r$ or $k=(2r-1)$, craft a **separate** formula for each, and then try to **consolidate** the two formulas into a single *universal* formula that will be accurate **regardless** of whether $k$ is odd or even.

Comment: If $ k=2r$ , it's $ \frac{k}{2} - 1=r-1 $, if $ k=2r+1 $ , its $ r= \frac{k-1}{2} $. So it should be $ \lfloor \frac{k-1}{2} \rfloor $ am I right?

Comment: @Mattia_Borriello Yes, that's it.